# JSON file VS SQLite android

Tags: android, performance, json, sqlite, csv

I will develop an android application with a lot of data (json files with some rows and CSV for graphics data with a lot of rows) , this data change every 5 minutes and replaces all the previous data (or mostly).

What are the best approaches to design this ? I have 2 options:

- Save all the data in a sqlite db, and sync this by a IntentService.
- save the data in json and csv files and replace this every 5 minutes.

Which approach will the best performance?
This considering the time to parse the files, sorting data, the download time and the consistency of data.

any other ideas?

PD:I need a cache system too, in case if i don't have internet and I need the previous stored data

Comment: From where you are going to get lots of data?

Comment: financial data from our web server

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Sqlite` is mostly used when you want data to be saved and used in future. In your case data is changing every `5 minutes` so its better to have `JSON` because every time to make the `Database connection` `store` and `retrieve` after `5 minutes` will take some time.

**UPDATE:**

I also had the same Application in which the data was changing every time. In that case I used `Map<K, V>` and `ArrayList` to maintain the values, because as the data is changing everytime I think its not feasible to store the data in Sqlite everytime. It needs much time to perform DB Connection store, retrieve, update the data in Sqlite.

Answer (score 20):

Advantages of SQLite:

- Changes are ACID
- You can make complex requests faster (e.g. "give me only fields A,B from items with (C/D)>E")
- I would bet more compact for big data (integers are stored as integers instead of a string of individual digit)
- Only one file
- You can merge old data with new data easily
- You can update current data, even while using it
- Concurrency can be handled

Advantages for JSON/CSV:

- Easier to debug (plain text)
- Faster to make a whole update (copy the new file + delete the old one)

For the original question the whole delete/replace of the data makes JSON/CSV the winner.

However, if the application was to retrieve partial data every 10s and merge/update it with the previous one, SQLite would be a better option.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using JSON or some type of object serialisation unless:

- You need ACID compliance for write operations
- You need to report against the data which may involve copying the data to an external RDBMS
  or
- You wish to join those complicit in the overuse / abuse of databases, as commonly seen nowadays

Comment: Hmmm....someone backed me up on this, presumably on the last point also. Perhaps I need to start a movement. Anyway, good old object serialisation is often the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should depend on whether you need the previous data, for maybe comparing it with current data and so on. As a thumb rule, I use SQLite when you need the data to be stored and retrieved at a later stage. In case the data is only for display, I would rather keep it in program memory. Mind you this does not involve file operation.

Comment: I need a cache system too, in case if i don't have internet and i need the previous stored data

Comment: that is fine do not overwrite/delete data unless you get the new data in correct format. This way your old data would continue to be in memory and being used.

Answer (score -11):

Purpose of JSON and SQLite is completely different from each other

- JSON = is used send and receive data between server and client.
- SQLite= is used to store data.

Comment: REST is used to send and receive data between server and client.  JSON and SQLite both store data.  But yes you can Post JSON data with RESTful methods faster.

Comment: JSON is used for storing data as well.

Comment: Json is actually very commonly used for storing data, SQLite is better if the data can be broken to multiple separate tables with connection.

Comment: Its also possible to send sqlite db-files via http...

Comment: "is used send and receive data between server and client" - it's also a popular storage format, but typically not database-grade storage. Yet, databases like [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/introduction/) do in fact use JSON for database-grade data storage. The first point is blatantly wrong and an extreme oversimplification of JSON's role